# How to make a c++ code can be used in both Qt project (QTL style) and C++ project (STL style)

Tags: qt, stl, qvector

Is there any way to convert C++(STL) code to QT (QTL)?

I have a code written using STL (string, vector, iostream, fstream) and 
I want to add it to my Qt Project (QString, QVector, ... when used).
My ideal way is to make it QTL-STL-compatible by adding some defines
in `.h` file like following

```
// STL to QTL
#ifdef STL_CPP
    #include <string>
    #include<vector>
#else // QTL
    #include <QString>
    #define string QString
    #include <QVector>
    #define vector QVector
#endif
```

Is there any existing work can convert some most commonly used STL code without 
changing the source code ?

**Note that I don't want to convert std datatype to qt datatype**, what I want is to 
make a code can used in both Qt project(ifndef `STL_CPP`) and C++ project (ifdef `STL_CPP`).

Comment: Maybe you should show a small example of actual code. I am trying to understand why  `QVector::fromStdVector(const std::vector<T> &vector)` and `QString::fromStdString(const std::string &str)` does not solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Macro Substitution to convert STL-style code to QTL-style code is dangerous
and may cause many unexpected errors.

To avoid that, you can use the STL in QT code and convert when interacting with the Qt framework (for a price paid in performance),

convert STL datatype to QTL datatype is quite simple, just like `QVector::fromStdVector(const std::vector<T> &vector)` and `QString::fromStdString(const std::string &str)` mentioned by *drescherjm*